# Spring Data JpaRespositories consolidation

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

I write a web application with Spring Boot and now I'm facing with the following problem:

I have a following Service class:

```
@Service
class ExampleService {

@Autowired
ARepository aRepository;

@Autowired
BRepository bRepository;

@Autowired
CRepository cRepository;

}
```

All repository interfaces extends

```
JpaRepository<MatchingClass, Integer>
```

Now I would like to perform following crud operations for each repository:

```
public List<AClass> getAll() {
    List<AClass> aElements = new List<>();
    aRepository.findAll().forEach(x->aElements.add(x));
    return aElements;
}

public AClass getOne(Integer id) { return aRepository.getOne(id);}

public void addOne(AClass aClass) { aRepository.save(aClass);}

public void deleteOne(Integer id) {aRepository.delete(id);}

}
```

How can I achieve it without repeating methods with different parameter types? I have a basic knowledge about generics in java, but I'm not sure using it is permitted in spring data and, actually how to accomplish it properly.

Comment: Is Java8 being used ? An interface that extends JPARepository, with all your methods implemented as default interface methods should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

If your repository interfaces are already extending `JpaRepository<T, ID>` then you don't need the methods `deleteOne`, `addOne`, `getOne` you could use the methods in `JpaRepository` direclty.

For example simply call from your service the methods `delete`, `save`, `findOne`, etc:

```
aRepository.save(aClassEntity);
```

Check `org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository`.